# how can i sort time from begin to end as time series [PHP]

Tags: php

I have mixed time of array to be sorting, it is a string "1:30","3:20","2:10" i want to be it **"1:30","2:10","3:20"**
is there anyone can help me for this question, i am confused. Sorting time array

array to be sorting: time

```
$arr = array("1:30","3:20","2:10");
```

after sorting: time

print like this: **1:30,2:10,3:20**

Comment: What about `sort($arr);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spaceship(<=>) operator for the same,

```
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a) <=> strtotime($b);
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/v664X)

**O/P**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1:30
    [1] => 2:10
    [2] => 3:20
)
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.